Running html5 canvas jquery art animation server-side and show it client-side?
Could be my question makes no sense, so don't shoot me :)
I have an html5 canvas jquery art animation that starts with a random situation (so pre rendering is not an option, I suppose). I want to show it on my website, but since it's client-side, the smoothness depends on the visitor's cpu's capabilities.
Is there a way to run it server-side and show it on my website, so its smoothness only depends on my server's capabilities, I can tweak it accordingly and every viewer has the same experience?
I have no clue where to start. I read about Node.js and the likes, but I don't see how my script would fit in ...
